# Enjoy our workplace

Tags: discussion

I was just reading this question:

[“Should We Enjoy at our Workplace or should we Work all the time”?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/34890/5114)

I agree that as currently written this is off topic.
But if I we change the focus to be about;

"What activities are good for promoting team cohesiveness so that in the **long term** they are more focused".

Is that still to vague or unfocused?

What I would really like, is to find concepts/techniques, philosophies that can be applied at a work place that promotes worker well being (for the worker) and increased productivity (for the company).

Answer (score 9):

The rewording of the question to ask for a list of activities turns the question into a polling question.  Unfortunately, that's not what we're looking for on Stack Exchange.

Instead, can you think of a way to describe a real, actual problem in the workplace -- something that isn't so overly broad? Perhaps there's a clarifying question you can ask the asker in the comments to get that person to think more deeply about why this is a problem. If you can help uncover a real problem to solve, then it's possible to make something similar to this work.  The key is to add more specific details, or get the asker to add more specific details. Hope this helps.